# Do QuerySet operations on prefetched relationships hit the database?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

Let's say I query `Workplace`s in a `City` and prefetch all their `Worker`s, which is a many-to-many relationship:

```
workplaces = list(city.workerplace_set.filter(num_employees__lte=350).prefetch_related('Worker'))
```

If I use any `QuerySet` operation on `Worker`s from any of the `Workplace`s, will the database be hit or not? I could not make out a clear answer from the docs.

```
workplaces_with_interns = [workplace for workplace in workplaces 
                           # is this filter going to query the database?
                           if workplace.worker_set.filter(salary=0).exists()]
```

PS: someone is probably going to point out that I can reach the same answer by simply making a query for `city.workerplace_set` instead of making it a `list`. Yes, I know, but that is not possible because I am *caching* the `workplaces` so that the database is not hit every time the function that does all this is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This will hit the database because you are running a specific query - exists on a filter - that was not present in the original prefetch.

In your case, since you already have the workers, it would be better to filter them in Python:

```
[workplace for workplace in workplaces 
 if any(w.salary == 0 for w in workplace.worker_set.all())]
```

Alternatively, if this is the only reason you need the prefetch, you could use a Prefetch object in the original query to only fetch the workers with 0 salary.

(Just noticed you are using 1.4, which doesn't have Prefetch objects. You should definitely upgrade; not only for that reason, but mainly because 1.4 is very old and unsupported, and is therefore certainly a security risk.)

Comment: So any other query other than `workplace.worker_set.all()` will hit the DB?